# CGEL: Clarification on the Given Rules for Contrasting Constituents with 'But'

Tags: conjunctions, coordinating-conjunctions

Please could someone clarify a statement in The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language by Huddleston and Pullum?

On page 1311 (under section 2.5 'But'), the text makes this comment:

> A single difference [between coordinates linked by *but*] is sufficient if it is located in a predicative or modifying element, but hardly otherwise.

My misunderstanding relates to what the 'otherwise' options are. I have not read the entirety of CGEL, so I may be misinformed as to the book's definition of a 'predicative element', but my general understanding is that the predicate is everything except for the subject.

This would include the object, but the one example the book gives of an incorrect contrast (iv) highlights the object as being insufficient (see below):

> A single difference is sufficient if it is located in a predicative or
> modifying element,but hardly otherwise
>
> [54] i She loved her husband but betrayed him. [predicator]
>
> ii He was [rich but very mean]. [predicative comp]
>
> iii He had a [demanding but low-paid] job in the public service.
> [modifier]
>
> iv *She likes opera but (she likes) chamber music. [object]

To fix this, the book says you would need an additional element, such as 'too' in 'She likes opera, but (she likes) chamber music too.'

Having looked through the section of the book that talks about predicative elements, I noticed that 'object' is separated. Does CGEL not classify this as a 'predicative element'? If so, are the 'hardly otherwise' constituents that the book mentions the subject, object, and indirect object?

Comment: 'She likes opera, but she likes chamber music' does not offer the necessary contrastive. // 'She likes opera, but she likes chamber music / rap too' has a covert contrastive with opera-only fans. It might be considered at least mildly surprising that 'she' would like both opera and chamber music (or perhaps more realistically rap). But the CGEL classifications lose me.

Comment: It’s saying that, in the examples given in [54], there’s not a “difference” (contrast) in opera/chamber music. Cf. the other examples where there is contrast: loved/betrayed; rich/mean; demanding/low-paid.

Comment: A PC is a complement of a verbvrelated to a predicand, Subjects and objects typically function as predicands, and the PCs are usually NPs or AdjPs.

Comment: She likes opera but he likes MotoCross.  She likes hiking but only in the summer.  The dog growls at everyone but her. Are these considered "coordinates"?

Comment: The question becomes clearer when context is give: A single difference is sufficient if it is located in a predicative or modifying element, but hardly otherwise: -- [54]iShe loved her husband but betrayed him. [predicator] -- ii He was [rich but very mean].[predicative comp] -- iii He had a [demanding but low-paid] job in the public service. [modifier] -- iv *She likes opera but (she likes) chamber music. [object]

Comment: @MJAda The point is that an object is insufficient to qualify as a single difference. In the case of [54] iv "and" is required. And objects are not, of course, predicative or modifiers.

Comment: Thanks, @BillJ. You've cleared that up. Do you have a reference in CGEL for that? Just so I can bookmark it for later reference. I'm basically just looking for the place where CGEL defines the predicative element as you have. Also, if you don't mind, please could you post an answer to the question so I can accept it? You've basically confirmed that yes, the object (and indirect object?) and subject are not considered 'predicative elements', but predicands. 'Predicative elements,' I take it, is another description for predicative complements, as described in CGEL.

Comment: Note that 'She likes opera but she _likes_ chamber music' again shows contrast, the stress (conveying '_really_ likes') showing the contrast 'but' requires.

Comment: @MJAda Yes, predicative elements consist mainly of predicative complements. CGEL covers predicatives on pp. 251-72.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's very interesting! Your point shows that the contrasting elements of 'but' are displayed both syntactically and prosodically. Through writing, I guess the correct way to display this would be through formatting, such as italics.

Comment: Written attempts to reproduce the nuances of the spoken language do get better over time, but never really achieve perfection.

Comment: I'm sorry but this: She likes opera but she *likes* chamber music'  without really is just very odd. even if the second like is hysterically stressed. It is very unlikey.

Comment: @Lambie, to me, the italics imply 'really likes'. Another similar example could be 'I love you, but I _love_ him.' I think in a scenario where you're comparing a friendship to a romantic interest and trying to emphasise the difference, this isn't that unusual.

Comment: @MJAda Like I said, it would be extremely unlikely. You are repeating what I said and Ashforth said about stressing the verb, which goes against huddle and pull 'em. One can do many things with intonation but one cannot make it heard here.  You really would have to stretch it out and a man would never do that kind of stressing.